# Typescript return types when "playing" with strings

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

typescript fans!

I have a function, that takes in a URL (e.g. "localhost:3000/common/123") and returns the first string after the first "/".

```js
type UserType = "common" | "root" 
export const getUsertypeFromURL = (path: string): UserType => {
    const secondSlashIndex = path.indexOf('/', 1)
    const userType = path.substring(1, secondSlashIndex)
    // typescript error on the following line
    return userType
}
```

By definition, I know for sure that the output of `getUsertypeFromUrl` belongs to `UserType`.

I want to prevent typescript from displaying  the error `"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UserType'"`

What is the best approach to problems like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "By definition, I know for sure that the output of getUsertypeFromUrl belongs to UserType" no you don't, which is why the compiler is complaining. What if someone else (incl. you 6 months from now) calls it with a string that isn't a path? Or is a path but doesn't conform to the schema? You can pass any string to that function the compiler will not save you. The *easiest* way to fix this is to make sure that return value is strictly equal to one of the two string literals.

Comment: Can you provide some code @JaredSmith on how to make sure that return value is strictly equal to one of the two string literals?

Comment: The same way you would in plain Javascript? `if (userType === 'common' || userType === 'root') { return userType; } else { throw new TypeError('Argument is not one of the expected paths'); }` Unless we're talking about literal constants in the source the compiler isn't going to be able to prove at compile-time that an arbitrary string is a specific value. All it can do is check to make sure that you add appropriate runtime checks, which is why it rejected your code.

Answer (score 2):

I might approach it as follows [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIBEFEDEEkBy1wBUCaAFaBlcJgAoQgYwHsA7AZwBdwBVHaAJQH0Ns8BecAbQCJyAWyGV%20AGnD8ATmTI1%20AXXABDKuHLUaAbkI0AngAcApgyrHpqI6Z4BZY0IBGFgPIAzADwGTZNwyZsHLgAfLqEoBDwtpgAMtC20Iio4NAAGqjMAIIAwqguzPhEhG4ArhQkNACWlODGAB400ioV9OaW1gAU0sZUZCXSJMYAXLTSlRQA5gCUQ2YWViYA3oTgGpS04OaaACY4ADZqABbwFNv14Dzdvf2DAHTjZ3XuHfzAEuAAjFO6q5obJW0FjZwFc%20gNjLcqCVHKNxhMOh9JFtKLsDlRjqd6t8VuBKn4OgBCSpUexOCwdRgsdhYXCSAHzaxTKbgZarVY0Q6yADu4Aoxh50GksmkHQABicAG4qPaVbZzdomcAAEkW9IVxgAvrUGk0KsY5W5ZEJlYtQTdNaLsasNTjujR%20hRwGqgbobeEwOBspkmHgCMRgMBwFyyNIANZw8CkdZ0eoqISGPbGD6zVoMxU8eqNZo0VPqjo417CUQUYBUPahgBWVG2bn4hGxfxjdTjCeMACYU4DrBdtVmWl2TC9gLJ5KWyEJjBy4WOJ1PJvxsVHqGRE7c9mR4QApHAuRCQxpwvH6DqLbUtxOIs-xxNt8AaplhCK8mrBsNw24McrjicUOiUUwqHQKjgFUE6qKcGgyiQobgMwZQgWQ4CGLIEoQisEDQM0hwgZyZBcuoKiOhYwrgDKoamOKFBSjKcq5kC4ByE2fY0Pq4CGuOIKMTOk6HHCoroUUAZrFotRCiG%20rQM217DPK9EZjq2Z0Z0Mhcb0s68fOUzhIGjaicKElSa2nZpsCma6jmA7GC8ak8dOI4KFpQm6cR4nbJJ54yUp6a9uZXlWfwhw0DQhhUEMAY2XOEy3MIw6qeOtmacQ7oQPQqDwDE8AYGgNJ4JkiCQOAsD0IguTwLuvpFKU5RVDUxKks40geJkQq9sYpzqMwxgqNslB7PozVNPoHhlKGFB4RQwTBPmqwqEKswDeIOIkIR2yyoBMkjWNXIUPWszLaca0sbi6j1a4ngDcELK2pODqqEK9zlHsJRnFQHT7at2zrdibreKYp3SO4TVCio%20ite1IJdT1FB9U6FCjeNvCKJdPADSDvAUCUZLSIouhAA). Note I've renamed the function as it doesn't accept a URL. If you, future you, or someone else included a protocol in the URL, your logic would break.

The crucial step is to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (function that returns a predicate). You will cast a reference to a different type, in a way that's guarded conservatively by runtime checks.

I have shared some utility code that I often use to compose a guard from a runtime list, which I find makes the process easier. Hover over UserType and you will see it has the same effect as a type declaration, but also includes the information you need for the runtime check to happen.

I've preserved your extract implementation although I wouldn't write code like that myself - I would write an `extractFirstPathElement(url:string)` function based on regex, allowing for e.g. an optional protocol to be in the pattern like `([a-z]+://)?` and therefore ACTUALLY handling URLs.

Having named functions also self-documents that you're extracting the first path element from a URL string as a by-product.

```js
/** DEFINE TYPES */

const USER_TYPES = ["common", "root"] as const;
type UserType = MemberOf<typeof USER_TYPES>;

/** IMPLEMENT EXTRACTOR */

function extractUserType(resource:string): UserType{
  const secondSlashIndex = resource.indexOf("/", 1);
  const userType = resource.substring(1, secondSlashIndex);
  if (!isMember(USER_TYPES, userType)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid UserType ${userType} extracted from ${resource}`);
  }
  return userType;
}

/** CASES */

// working 
const example1: UserType = extractUserType(
  "/common/slkjsdf"
);
const example2: UserType = extractUserType("/root/something/something");

console.log(JSON.stringify({ example1, example2 }));

/** non working. Uncomment one at a time and click Run to prove.
 * Each throws an error like `Invalid UserType oot extracted from root/something`
 */

// const erroredExample: UserType = extractUserType("root/something")
// const erroredExample: UserType = extractUserType("something/root")
// const erroredExample: UserType = extractUserType("https://something.com/root/something")

/** UTILITY TYPES AND FUNCTIONS */

function isMember<Arr extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>>(
  arr: Arr,
  candidate: unknown
): candidate is MemberOf<Arr> {
  return arr.includes(candidate);
}

type MemberOf<Array extends readonly unknown[]> = Array[number];
```

Comment: Ideally we should not be messing with URL strings ourselves. Use the built in URL API to parse URLs. There's lots of valid URLs that would give unexpected results for this code.

Comment: That is my normal approach, but the OP already seems to be working with URLs that are not URLs based on his example `const url = new URL("localhost:3000/common/123");` creates an entry in which `url.host` is `""`. How they got in that pickle I don't know. My proposal was to handle URLs including their pseudo-urls by authoring an opinionated regex that will reliably pull out the first path element from a url-ish thing including an actual URL if someone mistakenly passed one in the future.

Answer (score 1):

cefn's is answer is correct, you don't want that function to assert that `userType` is the type `UserType`. That relies on the user of that function to give the right data for the function to work properly, and if you don't there will not be any error.

But the way to do that would be with `as` (Again, DON'T do this)

```js
return userType as UserType;
```

This is a more specific solution to your question:

```js
const UserType = ["common", "root"] as const;
type UserType = typeof UserType[number];
const isUserType = (value: string): value is UserType => {
    return UserType.includes(value as UserType);
};

export const getUsertypeFromURL = (path: string): UserType => {
    const secondSlashIndex = path.indexOf("/", 1);
    const userType = path.substring(1, secondSlashIndex);
    if (!isUserType(userType)) {
        throw new Error(...);
    }
    return userType;
};
```

Comment: I like the approach and doing it specifically is clearer (although I've had to do it so much in my typical codebases that the general approach helps). I strongly advise against having the static global const name 'shadow' the type name, which will trip future devs. The use of CAPS for statics is a common convention across a few languages but anything distinct from the type name is better (e.g. `userTypeList` if that's more your style). Unrelated to the shadowing, in code review I would reject any runtime value that had PascalCase. In Typescript, that is conventionally reserved for types.

Comment: Your approach is pretty sensible, but I think it's clearer when they shadow each other. The type and the value is very much connected, they are kind of two perspectives of the same thing. Also I've always worked with classes being PascalCase and they are implicitly 'shadowed', since a class is both a value and a type. But I can definitely see why that might be confusing if you never seen that before.

Comment: Sadly not everyone has your Typescript skills, for a junior dev this might be a pattern they try to recreate and lose an hour because it suggests that Typescript isn't a pure type-erasure language (like terrible Enums). Why is it an error when I call XType.includes? It worked for UserType. Or maybe they want to sensibly move these supporting functions to their own file for separation of concerns, but find they can't export both the type and the runtime list the moment this support mechanism is externalised to a module? Names are cheap. Totally agree classes PascalCase but not refs to instances

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, maybe I have to rethink that.